# Unique records in search query including many to one subquery

Tags: ms-access, search, duplicates, unique

First time poster and enthusiastic Access newbie.

I've got a search screen based on Allen Browne's wonderful search in vba (http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html).  This has worked great for most of my purposes, but now a child table is duplicating records.

Our clients(providers), can be enrolled in multiple programs.  we've got four.  I want a search that let's me filter by provider type, but not create duplicate records when a provider is enrolled in more than one provider type.  In the example image, carmen titus is in the LEHRC and fccn programs, and therefore shows up twice.  Tried to post pic but no dice.

Please help!  I searched diligently and could not find a solution.  I'd appreciate the support or to be pointed to a related post.  I hope this makes sense.  I think half my battle as a self-trained newbie is not knowing the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more info!

It sounds like the query you are basing the search on contains columns from two tables with a one to many relationship ie clients and "Client programs", such that a single client has zero to 4 programs.

It sounds like you only want to return a list of providers (ie rows on the one side), but your SQL is returning data from both tables.

Here's what you SQL might need to look like to do what you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients AS mainClient
WHERE 
EXISTS 
(SELECT 1
   FROM clients  AS C
        LEFT JOIN ClientPrograms  AS CP
        ON C.ID = CP.ClientID
   WHERE mainClient.ID = C.ID       
        ' the above line links the EXISTS "Sub query" to the main query
     AND client name like "*j*" ... etc...
         ... ie lots of criteria generated by you popup search criteria dialogue)
)
```

By adding the EXISTS statement the main query will be editable.

If you had used SQL like the following you would not be able to edit it

```
SELECT c.name, c.dob, etc.. ie all the field you want on the form whichwill all be from the client table
   FROM clients  AS C
        LEFT JOIN ClientPrograms  AS CP
        ON C.ID = CP.ClientID
   WHERE mainClient.ID = C.ID       
        ' the above line links the EXISTS "Sub query" to the main query
     AND client name like "*j*" ... etc...
         ... ie lots of criteria generated by you popup search criteria dialogue)
GROUP BY all the field in the select statement
```

I hope this gives you some inspiration

Comment: Thank you so much for the inspiration.  I'll get cracking and report back.  Many thanks,

Comment: Did you get it to work?  If so can you flag my response as an answer and up arrow it...ta.

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.

Comment: Argh, sorry i haven't been able to mine much time to dedicate to it other than a quick failed attempt.  I came up with an adequate work around, but look forward to dedicating more time to it.  but in any event definitely useful advice and I will follow up with success or failure.  many thanks.

Comment: Ok.  Would you mind up voting or flagging it as an answer anyway?  (I'm trying to get my score up).  It sounds like you're busy.  It's the way of the world now!